# Why isn't this code playing any sound?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, trigonometry

I'm trying to get this to play a sine wave at 440 hz.
The constructor gets called, and no errors appear.
generate() makes an array of `double`s for the sound data, and sends it to process() which makes an array of `byte`s that try to get through a `Clip`

Thanks

```
public class Synth {

AudioFormat format;

public Synth(){
    format=new AudioFormat(44100, 1, 1, true, false);
    try{
    generate(0.5);
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

public void process(double[] data) throws Exception{ //range -1 to +1
    Clip clip=AudioSystem.getClip();

    byte[] bdata=new byte[data.length];
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        bdata[i]=(byte)(data[i]*127);
    }

    AudioInputStream a=new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bdata), format,bdata.length);

    clip.open(a);
}

public void generate(double seconds)throws Exception{
    float samplerate=format.getSampleRate();

    double[] data=new double[(int)(seconds*samplerate)];
    int f=440;

    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        data[i]=Math.sin(f*((double)(i)/samplerate)*2*Math.PI);
    }

    process(data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling [`Clip.loop(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#loop%28int%29) (or [`DataLine.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#start%28%29) - implemented by `Clip`).